# Spring Rest Template calls in java

Tags: java, spring, rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Hi I am trying to call some Soft layer APIs and was able to make simple calls as well as calls which include passing some ids using Spring's RestTemplate in java, but not able to make a similar call in java for below rest URL.

```
// formatted for readability
https://getInvoices?
objectFilter={  
   "invoices":{  
      "createDate":{  
         "operation":"betweenDate",
         "options":[  
            {  
               "name":"startDate",
               "value":[  
                  "06/01/2016"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "name":"endDate",
               "value":[  
                  "06/02/2016"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me out how to do the same in java using springs rest template or even using soft layer rest client.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help to get useful answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to user [Jersey Client API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html), your code could be like:

```java
String json = "{\"invoices\":{\"createDate\":{\"operation\":\"betweenDate\",\"options\":[{\"name\":\"startDate\",\"value\":[\"06/01/2016\"]},{\"name\":\"endDate\",\"value\":[\"06/02/2016\"]}]}}}";

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("https://api.softlayer.com")
                         .path("rest")
                         .path("v3")
                         .path("SoftLayer_Account")
                         .path("getInvoices")
                         .queryParam("objectFilter", 
                             URLEncoder.encode(json, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));

String result = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(String.class);
```

With [Spring RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), you would do:

```java
String json = "{\"invoices\":{\"createDate\":{\"operation\":\"betweenDate\",\"options\":[{\"name\":\"startDate\",\"value\":[\"06/01/2016\"]},{\"name\":\"endDate\",\"value\":[\"06/02/2016\"]}]}}}";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromUriString("https://api.softlayer.com")
        .path("rest")
        .path("v3")
        .path("SoftLayer_Account")
        .path("getInvoices")
        .queryParam("objectFilter", 
            URLEncoder.encode(json, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()))
        .build()
        .toUri();

String result = restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, String.class);
```

Comment: request generated by rest temp "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter=%257B%2522invoices%2522%253A%257B%2522createDate%2522%253A%257B%2522operation%2522%253A%2522betweenDate%2522%252C%2522options%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522startDate%2522%252C%2522value%2522%253A%255B%252206%252F01%252F2016%2522%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522endDate%2522%252C%2522value%2522%253A%255B%252206%252F02%252F2016%2522%255D%257D%255D%257D%257D%257D"                                    but resulted in 500 (Internal Server Error); invoking error handler

Comment: Unable to parse object filter.

Comment: @user3777871 I don't know this API. Instead of `URLEncoder.encode(json, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())` try just `json`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use RestTemplate

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String resourceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/resturl";
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceUrl+ "/1", String.class);
```

or you can go with httpclient